# Decreased sleep time for Yogis

Tags: scripture, yogi

We generally hear that yogis need less time for sleep compared to others.

Are there any scriptural statements that validate this statement?

Comment: vishvamitra revealed mantras bala & ati-bala to rama-lakshmana - one of them avoids the need of hunger, and the other avoid need of sleep. so there is atleast 1 scriptural reference for rishis/yogis not being dependent on sleep.